# Oracle sql function question

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

How to display the details of employee whose name contains the same characters at the start and end position of their name?

Comment: Smells like homework ...

Comment: homework hint: lookup the instr function and see if you can use that somehow in your query or maybe do something clever with regexp.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this using SUBSTR() to identify a portion of the ENAME.  The more orthodox approach works on the basis that passing a negative value as the offset counts from the *end* of the string:

```
SQL> select ename
  2  from emp
  3  where substr(ename,1,1) = substr(ename,-1,1)
  4  /

ENAME
----------
TROMBONIST

SQL>
```

Just for grins, I include the second approach which uses the undocumented REVERSE() function:

```
SQL> select ename, reverse(ename)
  2  from emp
  3  where substr(ename,1,1) = substr(reverse(ename),1,1)
  4  /

ENAME      REVERSE(EN
---------- ----------
TROMBONIST TSINOBMORT

SQL>
```

In 10g and higher we can also be solve this with regular expressions:

```
SQL> select ename
  2  from emp
  3  where regexp_substr(ename,'^.') = regexp_substr(ename,'.$')
  4  /

ENAME
----------
TROMBONIST

SQL>
```